# Name of operation: changing the root of a rooted tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

What is (if any) the name of the operation of changing the root of a rooted tree? Picking a vertex which is not the root, then reorienting the edges in such a way that the vertex becomes the root?

Comment: My vote is for "rerooting".